# Async search with jquery, ajax and json

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I'm working on a project for school. in this project, I have to make an async search bar to search data in a table in CodeIgniter, and this has to be done with JSON. The async search is working, but I don't think the way I'm doing it is with JSON. I would appreciate some help on how to do this with JSON.

Jquery in my view : `

```
$(document).ready(function(){

load_data();

function load_data(query)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajaxsearch/fetch",
        method:"POST",
        data:{query:query},
        success:function(json){
            $('#result').html(json);
        }
    })
}

$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    if(search != '')
    {
        load_data(search);
    }
    else
    {
        load_data();
    }
});
});
```

`

Controller : `

```
class Ajaxsearch extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('ajaxsearch');
}

function fetch()
{
    $output = '';
    $query = '';
    $this->load->model('ajaxsearch_model');
    if($this->input->post('query'))
    {
        $query = $this->input->post('query');
    }
    $data = $this->ajaxsearch_model->fetch_data($query);
    $output .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" >Channel Number</th>
                        <th scope="row">Channel Name</th>
                    </tr>
    ';
    if($data->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($data->result() as $row)
        {
            $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row->nr.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->naam.'</td>

                    </tr>
            ';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= '<tr>
                        <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
                    </tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    echo $output;
}

}`
```

Model :
    `

```
 <?php
   class Ajaxsearch_model extends CI_Model
  {
     function fetch_data($query)
     {
       $this->db->distinct('nr');
       $this->db->select("*");
       $this->db->from("kanalen");
       if($query != '')
     {
       $this->db->like('naam', $query);

    }
       $this->db->order_by('nr', 'DESC');
       return $this->db->get();
}
```

}
?>`

Error on line 51 : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7bSX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you create the data as an array in your controller, then pass it back with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and render the output on the client-side, I think it is more what you are looking for.  I excluded the Model, because it doesn't need to change, and the unchanged part of your jquery is omitted before/after the `...`

Javascript:

```
...

function load_data(query)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajaxsearch/fetch",
        method:"POST",
        data:{query:query},
        success:function(json){
            handleOutput(json);
        }
    });
}

function handleOutput(json) {
    var output = '<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-striped"><tr><th scope="row" >Channel Number</th><th scope="row">Channel Name</th></tr>';
    if (json.length == 0) { // if no data is returned
        output += '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td</tr>';
    } else {  // if data isn't returned
        json.forEach(function(row) {
            output += '<tr><td>'+row['nr']+'</td><td>'+row['naam']+'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
    output += '</table></div>';
    $('#result').html(output);
}

...
```

Controller:

```
class Ajaxsearch extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('ajaxsearch');
}

function fetch()
{

    $query = '';
    $this->load->model('ajaxsearch_model');
    if($this->input->post('query'))
    {
        $query = $this->input->post('query');
    }
    $data = $this->ajaxsearch_model->fetch_data($query);
    $retval = array();
    if($data->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $retval[] = array(
            "nr" => $row->nr,
            "naam" => $row->naam
        );
    }
    return json_encode($retval);
}

}
```

**Note:** I condensed your code a bit.  Hopefully, it is still easily read/understandable.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! i only have 1 question. Do I overwrite the already existing jquery that I wrote with your javascript?

Comment: @acesteef, the only thing that changed in your ajax call is `$('#result').html(json);` changed to `handleOutput(json);`.  If you change that and add the `handleOutput` function, everything else in your JS stays the same

Comment: It is giving me an error on line 51 in the function handleOutput. The error says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @acesteef The ajax call was unclosed.  My last edit should fix that error

Comment: Actually, I am not sure.  Which line is 51 in your version of the code?

Comment: There is another error and i cant seem to find the problem. The error says Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, in line 55 where you create the foreach.

Comment: I found the error but now its saying that forEach is not a function. Error : ncaught TypeError: json.forEach is not a function
    at handleOutput (ajaxsearch:56)
    at Object.success (ajaxsearch:45)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)